# Java IO socket not sending outputstream

Tags: java, sockets, java-io, java-stream

When debugging my code, the code stops here:

```
while (( msg = reader.readLine())  != null) {
        writer.write("From server: " + msg);
}
```

I am sending input from a client class, but I can't figure out where I am wrong, since the server never receives the message.

Here is my entire sever class:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Server {

    private BufferedReader reader;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private int port;

    public Server(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
    }

    private String getSeverAddress() {      
        String host = null;
        try {
            InetAddress adr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            host = adr.getHostAddress();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return host;
    }

    public void startServer() {

        print("Contact this sever on address: " + getSeverAddress() + " port: " + port);

        ServerSocket ss = null; 
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            socket = ss.accept();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            String msg = null;

            while (( msg = reader.readLine())  != null) {
                writer.write("From server: " + msg);
                print(msg);

                if(msg.toLowerCase().equals("Bye")) {
                    print("Client left");
                    break;
                }
            }

            ss.close();
            socket.close();
            reader.close();
            writer.close();

        } catch(SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
        } catch (IOException i ) {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }       

    private void print(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Server server = new Server(1111);
        server.startServer();

    }

}
```

And here is the client class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Client {

    private Socket client;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    public Client(Socket socket)
    {
        client = socket;

        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeToServer() {       
        print("Write message to server");

        String msg = null;

        try {
            while((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write("From client: " + msg);
                print(msg);

                if(msg.toLowerCase().equals("quit")) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            reader.close();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void print(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 1111);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        Client client = new Client(socket);
        client.writeToServer();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide errors message?

Comment: Both your server and your client are waiting for input from the other - what do you expect to be the first message sent? Also note that you're never sending a line break as far as I can tell, so `readLine` wouldn't know that it's reached the end of a line...

Comment: What is after recving message, writer.write("From server: " + msg);

Comment: Ye Win, there are no error messages. The server just waiting for input. I do write input from the client class, but it just never reaches the server

Comment: There is no received message.

I start the server, which then waits for client messages. 
I then start the client, and start writing messages to server, but the messages are never received by the server

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is server and client both sending/receiving messages background without printing anything. Like when you send message from client, Server received it and again write to the client and it become infinite loop.

Following things are wrong:

**Server.java**

```
 try {
         while (( msg = reader.readLine())  != null) {
            print(msg);
            if(msg.toLowerCase().equals("bye")) {
                print("Client left");
                break;
            }
            writer.write("From server: " + msg);
        }
```

Should be the last statement of loop  `writer.write("From client: " + msg);` and `if(msg.toLowerCase().equals("Bye"))` should `bye`

**Client.java**

```
try {
           while((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               print(msg);
                if(msg.toLowerCase().equals("quit")) {
                    break;
                }
              writer.write("From client: " + msg);
            }
```

It should be last in loop `writer.write("From client: " + msg);`

Comment: If I remover writer.write(...) from the client, how can I send the message then? the writer contains the outputStream of the socket. This is not an attack, I am just wondering

Comment: Edited! when you develop it in rich UI then it will get removed and It wrapped in `ActionListener` of Send button

Answer (score 0):

You're reading lines but you aren't sending lines. You need to send a line terminator.